# Doorkeeper oauth_access_tokens too large

Tags: doorkeeper

We are using the Doorkeeper gem for OAuth2. However, our oauth_access_tokens table is getting way too large.

- Are old access tokens supposed to be removed automatically? If so, why are they not removed, and is this perhaps a setting?
- If they are not removed automatically, what would be a good strategy to regularly purge old tokens?

Answer (score 3):

For mates who are googling for answer in **2019**.

Add this line to your `Rakefile`:

```rb
Doorkeeper::Rake.load_tasks
```

It will add some tasks to your environment:

```
rake doorkeeper:db:cleanup                 # Removes stale data from doorkeeper related database tables
rake doorkeeper:db:cleanup:expired_grants  # Removes expired (TTL passed) access grants
rake doorkeeper:db:cleanup:expired_tokens  # Removes expired (TTL passed) access tokens
rake doorkeeper:db:cleanup:revoked_grants  # Removes stale access grants
rake doorkeeper:db:cleanup:revoked_tokens  # Removes stale access tokens
```

Documentation can found [here](https://doorkeeper.gitbook.io/guides/internals/cleaning-up)

Answer (score 2):

> Are old access tokens supposed to be removed automatically? If so, why are they not removed, and is this perhaps a setting?

As I understand, it will not be removed automatically

> If they are not removed automatically, what would be a good strategy to regularly purge old tokens?

In my case, we used cron job to regularly check the database.
We delete the tokens which are already revoked and the tokens that is not yet revoked, but it has been more than some months (Anyway, this is just an example).
You can also change the lifespan of the token longer so it will produce less number of tokens, but you know that it is not recommended as security reason.

Hope it can help.